# Laravel: Get correct path for public upload

Tags: php, laravel-5, image-uploading

I am using as recommended in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads)

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('public/avatars');
```

to store my avatar. In the docs the following is mentioned:

> By default, the store method will generate a unique ID to serve as the
>   file name. The path to the file will be returned by the store method
>   so you can store the path, including the generated file name, in your
>   database.

Now the `$path` will be something like

```
public/pictures/uQT3sGS1mTQQXbB5vHwCYUiELtr2XAbl7cI08Mme.png
```

but the actual url to the picture is

```
/storage/pictures/uQT3sGS1mTQQXbB5vHwCYUiELtr2XAbl7cI08Mme.png
```

In the docs its stated that I can store `$path` directly in the database. But as I see it, one has to convert manually

```
public/pictures/uQT3sGS1mTQQXbB5vHwCYUiELtr2XAbl7cI08Mme.png
```

to

```
pictures/uQT3sGS1mTQQXbB5vHwCYUiELtr2XAbl7cI08Mme.png
```

so that I can use it later like

```
<img src="/storage/{{ $user->avatar }}">
```

Is there any Laravel option, so that `store` returns directly the correct link, or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper functions for custom path using `public_path()`  in Laravel 4, or `path('public')` in Laravel 3.

Comment: As far as I understood the helper `public_path()` leads to the `/public` folder, i.e. where the website is contained and not the public storage folder `/storage/public/`.

Comment: public_path() will give you the path for public and public_path('your_path') will give you path for public/your_path

Comment: yes. But my question is not how to use a helper function. And even if I wanted to get the path of `imagename.jpg` (which I don't), then `public_path` is the wrong helper, you would need to use `storage_path('app/public/imagename.jpg')`